# Error: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Tags: installation, sql, joomla-3.7

I am trying to install joomla 3.7.5. I am facing an Error message:

```
Error: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
The table '#__update_sites_extensions' is full
The table '#__update_sites' is full
The table '#__updates' is full
The table '#__ucm_history' is full
The table '#__ucm_content' is full
The table '#__ucm_base' is full
The table '#__template_styles' is full
The table '#__tags' is full
```

I can easily install on my Localhost and another server.

Comment: Can you give more details? Things become confusing when you say you get error but next that you can easily install on localhost and another server.

Comment: Is your database really empty?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the root cause of the problem is your InnoDB tables hitting the maximum size. Check the value of the `innodb_data_file_path` variable in your `my.cnf` file and increase it accordingly. Alternatively, you can set the value of `innodb_file_per_table` to 1 in your `my.cnf`, but beware [this may come at a cost](https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/02/24/mysqls-innodb_file_per_table-slowing/).

If you don't have any control over your `my.cnf` file, then you should talk to your host about it. I would say that most likely they will advise you to upgrade to a higher, more expensive, plan.